# Fact constellation for a retail network

Tags: data-warehouse

I am new to data warehousing and I need to design a fact constellation schema for a retail stores network. Can any body suggest me a good tutorial? I have seen rarely any on the web.

Answer (score 2):

The [Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247) is essential reading for data warehousing, and includes an entire chapter where retail sales is used as an example.